# Does zfs recordsize impact compressratio

Tags: postgresql, zfs

We host a postgresql95 OLAP database on zfs with lz4 compression turned on. As recommended we tuned the zfs recordsize to 8KB since this is postgres block size. The write ahead log is on it's own dataset with recordsize set to 1M:

```
NAME            PROPERTY    VALUE    SOURCE
ssd             recordsize  128K     default
ssd/pgdata      recordsize  8K       local
ssd/pgdata/log  recordsize  1M       local
```

I noticed that the log compressratio is much better. I wonder if the reason is that it is just more compressible or if the small recordsize really hurts the compressratio.

```
NAME            PROPERTY       VALUE  SOURCE
ssd             compressratio  1.84x  -
ssd/pgdata      compressratio  1.84x  -
ssd/pgdata/log  compressratio  2.64x  -
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it impacts compression ratio. I've gone back to 128K record size for Postgres because the poor compression at 8K wasn't worth the potential performance gains.

Comment: Could you please share your `zpool create` options you used to create volume for PSQL ?

Answer (score 1):

On ZFS, the Value set in recordsize is not a hard rule, its an upper limit:

> In ZFS all files are stored either as a single block of varying sizes
>   (up to the recordsize) or using multiple recordsize blocks.
>   From: https://blogs.oracle.com/roch/entry/tuning_zfs_recordsize

So i think the values you are seeing are related the the data that is stored.